# How to go to the line my program has crashed at? (in PyCharm)

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

When I run a program and it ends with an exception it looks like e.g.:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/majkl/PycharmProjects/tests/testy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "**C:/Users/majkl/PycharmProjects/tests/testy.py**", line 2, in <module>
print (1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The path **C:/Users/majkl/PycharmProjects/tests/testy.py** is a link to the line with error. I can click on it with a mouse. I want to "click" on it with a keyboard or do something with the same result.

In other words:
How can I go (position caret at) to line 2 (without using `ctrl + g` and typing 2) using keyboard only?  If it was a syntactic error I could use F2 key. But this was a runtime error

Trying PyCharm 5.0.3

Comment: shift + F1 go to previous error. for next error muss you set in setting. Or u can find it in Navigate -> Next highlighted error; previous highlighted error

Answer (score 1):

While checking out linuts' answer I found out the correct one.

Shortcuts ctrl + alt + down and ctrl + alt + up go up/down the stacktrace. You can use either in my case and combine appropriately in more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, also with 5.0.3, I can select the run output (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>) or debug output (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>).

Then I can move the cursor to the file name part of the line you're interested in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the appropriate line in that file.

Comment: I knew about alt + 4  (or ctrl + tab + 4), but enter doesn't do anything